# filter using mixitup via URL?

Tags: jquery

I am using Mixitup jquery plugin for this. Is there anyway I can add some parameters to the URL to tell the page to filter the items via URL? I was hoping for something like -

www.example.com/abc.html?filter=cats

Now when you see the page, only items within the category cats is visible by default.

I know we can trigger the filter like so

```
 $('#Grid').mixitup('filter','cats');
```

but this works for only when I am already on the page and mixitup has already initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had to do something similar recently, so I thought this might help others. This worked for me:

```
$('#Grid').mixitup(
   {'showOnLoad': 'cats'}
);
```

See the [documentation](http://mixitup.io/#ShowOnLoad).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use '#cats' in your url.
Then you can trigger click evens after certain time.
Please try this:

```
<script>
 var parts = window.location.hash;
 if (parts) {
   setTimeout( function () { jQuery(parts).click(); }, 850);
 }
```

I tried this. It must be work.